# Can't set TextureWic C++DirectX

Tags: directx

I am trying to use a texture embedded in a file, it's not a tga.

Here is my code, I don't know where the logical error is.

```
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* texturePtr = nullptr; 
ID3D11Texture2D* texture2D = nullptr;
ID3D11SamplerState* sampleStatePtr = nullptr;


hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));



devConPtr->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &sampleStatePtr);
devConPtr->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &texturePtr);


Texture2D tex : TEXTURE;
SamplerState mySampler : SAMPLER; 


D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC sd;
ZeroMemory(&sd, sizeof(sd));
sd.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
sd.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
sd.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
sd.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
sd.MipLODBias = 0.0f;
sd.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;
sd.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER;

hr = devPtr->CreateSamplerState(&sd, &sampleStatePtr);



DXGI_SAMPLE_DESC sample;

sample.Count = 1;
sample.Quality = 0;


D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc;

textureDesc.Width = w;
textureDesc.Height = h;
textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
textureDesc.SampleDesc = sample;
textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
textureDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA subData;

subData.pSysMem = data;
subData.SysMemPitch = sizeof(*data)*w;



HRESULT hr = devPtr->CreateTexture2D(
    &textureDesc,
    &subData,
    &texture2D
);
assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));


//(ID3D11Texture2D*)texture2D;

texturePtr->QueryInterface(IID_ID3D11Texture2D, (void**)&texture2D);


D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC shvD;

shvD.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
shvD.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;

hr= devPtr->CreateShaderResourceView(texture2D, &shvD, &texturePtr);

assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

hr = DirectX::CreateWICTextureFromMemory(devPtr, devConPtr, (const 
uint8_t*)&data, sizeof(*data), 
nullptr, &texturePtr, NULL);

assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));


unsigned int textureCount = mat->GetTextureCount(aiTextureType_UNKNOWN);

    for (UINT j = 0; j < textureCount; j++)
    {

        aiString* path = nullptr;
        mat->GetTexture(aiTextureType_UNKNOWN, j, path);

        assert(path->length >= 2);
        int index = atoi(&path->C_Str()[1]);
        createTexture(scenePtr->mTextures[index]->mWidth, scenePtr- 
>mTextures[index]->mHeight, (uint8_t*)scenePtr->mTextures[index]->pcData);
    }
```

If you could find some kind of logical error or help with the debugging that would be super helpful, I try to put a breakpoint at my HRESULTS but I can't find the variables however it does say that my resourceviewptr is always nullptr despite me trying to use it.

I am using c++ and directx and directx toolkit etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing `shvD` completely. To fix it, initialize it like this:

```
D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC shvD;

shvD.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
shvD.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
shvD.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
shvD.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;
```

Comment: ``D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC shvD  = {};`` is probably the best habit to get into, but you can also use the C++ helpers ``CD3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC shvD(D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D, DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM);``